# jqgrid, setting value of an editable select control

Tags: drop-down-menu, jqgrid

I have an editable grid, with one of its column is a SELECT type, e.g.

```
colModel:[{ name:'myText',index:'myTextColumn',editable: true, edittype: 'text'},   
          {name:'myList',index:'myList', width:editable: true,edittype: "select",
            editoptions: { value: {'v1':'Value 1','v2':'Value 2',....} },
          ............    
        ]
```

I use the method setRowData to set data in one of the rows by code. The value that I pass for the Select type cell is the option value,  e.g.

```
jQuery("#myGrid").setRowData( rowId, { myText:"Text 2", myList:"v2", ..... })
```

After executing this code, the text type cell displays "Text 2", as expected. However, the  the Select type cell displays "v2" not "Value 2". Only when I click that cell the display changes to "Value 2"

How can I force the select type cell display the correct value without the need for manual click later?

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I found the solution for this problem. Just add a formatter of type "select" to the column.
http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2kn0mlo1p.htm